# POST request with the REST Client extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the "REST Client" extension for Visual Studio Code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client.

I'm able to make a GET request with this code:

```
GET https://some.domain.com/search/someuser/somekey?foo=5&bar=1
```

and it works.

Now, I need to make a POST request and pass the `foo` and `bar` values as form fields.

I tried with:

```
POST https://some.domain.com/search/
Authorization: Basic someuser somekey
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

'foo'='5'
'bar'='1'
```

but I'm getting back an error `"Missing required parameter foo in the post body"`

What is the correct syntax for a POST request with REST Client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It works like this:

```
POST https://some.domain.com/search/
Authorization: Basic someuser somekey
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo='5'&bar='1'
```

- parameters need to be concatenated with `&`
- parameter names should
  not be put in between quotes